# Code quality - order of @Autowired member variables?

Tags: java, spring, code-conversion

How would you order member variable fields when also using injecte `@Autowired` and `@Value` annotations from `spring`?

Would you consider the following example as best practice?

```
public class MyExample {
    private static final Logger logger;
    private static final int STATIC_VAR = 1;

    @Autowired
    private WebService service;

    @Value("${my.property}")
    private String property;

    //to be set by setter or constructor
    private MailService mail;
}
```

Comment: I don't consider annotations, I encapsulate variables by their types. Anyway, it's primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the order of the instance members really matters. That said, I like to set them through the constructor so that they can be final:

```
public class MyExample {

  private static final Logger logger;
  private static final int STATIC_VAR = 1;

  private final WebService service;

  private final String property;

  private final MailService mail;

  @Autowired
  public MyExample(WebService service, @Value("${my.property}") String property) {
    this.service = service;
    this.property = property;
    mail = new MailService();
  }

}
```